# Unexpected Error when set price on Google Play Console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I got an unexpected error when trying to save the base plan.
Why do I get this error? How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insure Your Internet Connectivity. Some time occur due to slow internet speed

Comment: Thanks I try to switch internet and It works